# Javascript parameter dynamically change using Play

Tags: javascript, playframework

I have a javascript request like this to pass data to play framework and based on the different propertyKey, the event should have different parameter.

I do something like this.

The js is used by multiple windows. So this._propertyKey will change based on different windows.

```
_postEvent: function(customData) {
 var propertyKey = this._propertyKey;
 var Event = {
       propertyKey : customData
     },
     url = play.url({
       alias: 'controllers.eventController.trackEvent',
       args: Event,
       withCsrf: true
     });
 return $.ajax(url, {
   type: 'POST'
 });
},
```

The problem when I trigger this code. According to the request it sends, it is always Event.propertyKey instead of the customized propertyKey I pass in. For example, if for this window, propertyKey = 'region'. I want 'region' to pass in as the parameter. But no matter what propertyKey is, the post request always sends Event.propertyKey = XXX instead of Event.region = XXX.

Is there a way to pass in the propertyKey here Is use to make it change dynamically based on different pages?

Comment: What is `this`? Did you set it somewhere? Otherwise its value is `window`

Comment: I do not specify this. It should be window. This js is shared by multiple windows, that's why the propertyKey will change each time.

Comment: Actually, I just learned that what I said about `window` is incorrect. I'm going to post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

> When a function is called as a method of an object, its `this` is set to the object the method is called on.  [MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#As_an_object_method)

To fix that part of the code, use `window` instead of `this`.

In order to set a property name to be the value of another variable, you have to create the object first, and then set the key/value pair using `[]`. [SO Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274242/using-a-variable-for-a-key-in-a-javascript-object-literal)

```
var Event = {};
Event[propertyKey] = customData;
var url = play.url({
    alias: 'controllers.eventController.trackEvent',
    args: Event,
    withCsrf: true
});
```

Comment: I've updated my answer to help with using the `Event.propertyKey` issue also.